# Redireccion de pagina principal .htaccess con?

Tags: .htaccess

Mi página web está en **2 idiomas**: *Español* (`ejemplo.com/?lang=es`) y en *Inglés* (`ejemplo.com/?lang=en`).

Me gustaría saber cómo al entrar en la página, me rediriga a `?lang=es` automáticamente.

No sé si hay que usar `.htaccess` con la función **DirectoryIndex**, o qué

Comment: Entiendo que se puede hacer con htaccess y generar un redirect 301 a la página que comentas. Otra forma que he utilizado es en mi administrador de host( Google) puedo redirección mi dominio a otro sitio (tambien con un redirect 301) pero sin modificar el archivo raiz de forma directa. Saludos

Comment: Podrías crear algunas reglas en tu .htaccess o alternativa podrías controlarlo mediante una **cookie**, por ejemplo, si *cookie* idioma existe, rediriges según su valor, y si este no existe rediriges al idioma por defecto. De esta manera podrías guardar durante un tiempo el idioma preferido del usuario. Algo como:  ```if (isset($_COOKIE['lang'])) {  header('ejemplo.com/?lang=' . htmlspecialchars($_COOKIE['lang'])); } else { header('ejemplo.com/?lang=es'); }```

Comment: Buenas! Es una buena idea, pero como podría hacerlo? Soy muy principiante en esto jaja, perdona. Si me podrías echar un cable te agradecería. Gracias tio!

Answer (score 0):

Voy a dejarte un ejemplo para orientarte.

Por ejemplo, una opción de muchas otras seria la creación de **subdominios** para cada idioma diferente, este sería la manera más fácil y usado en mi ejemplo.

`tu-dominio.com`  (Página español) dominio original
`en.tu-dominio.com`  (Página ingles) subdominio

**Posible ejemplo:** 
*tu-dominio.com*

```
<?php 
// Por defecto
$idioma = $msg = '';

// Boton formulario existe
if (isset($_POST['cambiar'])) :
    // Obtenemos datos
    $idioma = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'idioma', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    // Comprobamos que no este vacio
    if (!empty($idioma)) :
        // Creamos cookie
        setcookie("lang",$idioma,strtotime( '+365 days' ),"/",false, true);

        if ($idioma=='es') :
            // Redirigimos dominio original
            header("location: www.tu-dominio.com");
        else :
            // Redirigimos subdominios
            header("location: {$idioma}.tu-dominio.com");
        endif;
    else :
        $msg = 'hubo problemas';
    endif;  
endif;

// Si existe cookie redireccionas al subdominio con otro idioma.
//
// Si la cookie es igual a la pagina actual no se redirige ($_COOKIE['lang'] !='es')
// Si estas en algun subdominio pongo como ejemplo EN, entonces este valor deberia ser asi $_COOKIE['lang'] !='en'

if (isset($_COOKIE['lang']) && $_COOKIE['lang'] !='es') :
    header("location: {$_COOKIE['lang']}.tu-dominio.com"); // seria:   en.tu-dominio.com (usas un subdominio)
endif;
?>

<h2>Selecciona un idioma</h2>

<form method="POST">
    <select name="idioma">
        <option value="0" selected>Selecciona idioma</option>
        <option value="es">ES</option>
        <option value="en">EN</option>
        <option value="nl">NL</option>
        <option value="etc">ETC</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="cambiar" value="Cambiar">
    <?php 
    if (isset($msg)) :
        echo $msg;
    endif;
    ?>
</form>
```

Recuerda en tu pagina *en.tu-dominio.com* debes cambiar esta linea, es decir, **'es'** por el idiomia del subdomio por ejemplo **'en'** si es ingles.

`if (isset($_COOKIE['lang']) && $_COOKIE['lang'] !='es') :`

por

`if (isset($_COOKIE['lang']) && $_COOKIE['lang'] !='en') :`